# Proper Oracle SQL to identify primary keys that share a combination of values

Tags: sql, oracle

There is most likely a simple solution to this question, but I've found myself stuck and can't find another question similar to this that's been posted. So, I have a table (`SUPPLIERS`) that identifies stores and their suppliers.

| StoreID | SupplierID |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | 001 |
| 123456 | 002 |
| 123456 | 003 |
| 234567 | 001 |
| 345678 | 001 |
| 345678 | 002 |
| 456789 | 001 |
| 456789 | 004 |

I need to identify the stores where a specified supplier was used in combination with a specified group of suppliers. So from the above `SUPPLIERS` table, I need to obtain all Store IDs where supplier `001` was used with `002` AND/OR `003`.

I've tried...

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT StoreID
FROM
   SUPPLIERS
WHERE 
     SupplierID = 001
AND (SupplierID = 002
      or
     SupplierID = 003);
```

...but I'm not returning what I'd expect. From the above I would expect:

| StoreID |
| --- |
| 123456 |
| 345678 |

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> select distinct a.storeid
  2  from suppliers a
  3  where a.supplierid = '001'
  4    and exists (select null
  5                from suppliers b
  6                where b.storeid = a.storeid
  7                  and b.supplierid in ('002', '003')
  8               );

   STOREID
----------
    123456
    345678

SQL>
```